# How do I fix a bug in an open source R package?

Tags: r

I'd like to fix a package, but can't figure out how to edit it.  I can [download the source from R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=316) as a .tar.gz and unzip it.  There is an "R" directory with the source and also a "tests" directory.

How do I include the sources in my own project to test my edits?

How do I run the tests?  The tests each start with "library(blotter)".  How do I make that load the library from the sources I've downloaded.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384598/how-to-edit-r-library-sources?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found that I could load all the sources to save me from the ridiculous repackaging by doing:

```
for (file in dir("../R", pattern="*.R", full.names=TRUE)) {
  source(file)
}
```

Comment: A similar function is included in the examples of `?source`... but I'm really not helping since you know how to read the manual, right?

Answer (score 4):

The recommended process is described in some detail in the manual 'Writing R Extensions' that came with your R installation.

There are also numerous tutorials all over the web.

Comment: @Ben McCann: He did not yust tell you to RTFM, he pointed you to the right one...

Comment: Hehe, I'll try to be less blunt next time.  I do appreciate the help.  The thing that's so great about stack overflow is that you can get specific answers to quick questions.  I do appreciate pointers to specific sections of the manual with perhaps an excerpt included :o)  Less helpful is oh it's somewhere in those 141 pages.

Comment: If you appreciate the help, up-vote the answer.  And rest assured you will have to read more than 141 pages if you want to put R to good use. Much more.

Answer (score 2):

No need to re-zip the source. Just load the package again from the source on your drive:

```
install.packages(/path/to/package, repos = NULL, type="source")
```

your method of doing the for loop to loop across R files will work in some situations but in others it may not. For example, if there is compiled non R code then looping across the *.R files may not work properly. So it's generally better to just install.packages() again.

BTW, if you clone a version control repo to your hard drive you generally don't get the zip file. So the same method is used to install.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is the following (IIRC) remove the old package `remove.packages`.  Re zip your new package to a tar.gz file again (with your changed sources).  Install the new package with `install.packages` with pkg = path to your zipped library, and repos=NULL.

Comment: wow. that's an incredible pain. is there anyway to do it without having to continually zip my source code after each change I make?

Comment: You've go a computer, automate it.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm doing testing on a package, I use a little bash script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#build the package from source
R CMD build ../pkgdirectory/
#remove the old version and install the new one
R CMD REMOVE pkgname
R CMD INSTALL pkgname_0.7.tar.gz
```

Replace package name with the appropriate names.  Save it as "make" and then run it whenever you finish a major edit.  Then your testing scripts can use library(pkgname) just like normal.

Comment: You can skip the remove step; it is done for you the install that follows. You could however add a `R CMD check` step, based on the tarball you created.

Comment: Thanks for the remove tip.  Yeah, I often include the check, especially in the early stages of putting a package together, but when I'm only tweaking code, I skip that step since it takes a while.