# R -- Editing the 'nnet' Package

Tags: r, nnet

I am trying to edit the R 'nnet' package.  I have done some poking around, but am unfamiliar enough with R itself so as to not be able to make any headway.

I have tried `trace("nnet", edit=TRUE)`, as outlined in a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384598/how-to-edit-and-debug-r-library-sources).  This results in the editor being opened and displaying:

```
       function (x, ...) 
       UseMethod("nnet")
```

I'm not entirely sure what to do with this...

I've also found that it is part of the "VR Bundle"; it has been suggested [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-see-source-code-of-nnet-package-td838773.html) that the source bundle be opened to view the code, but don't know a) how to go about doing this or b) if that would achieve anything as I would then need to modify and run the code..

My goal is to add/modify a parameter `minIt` that would insure a minimum number of epochs be achieved prior to termination of the training.

Thanks!

Comment: You can look at the methods: `methods(nnet)` and search for `[].formula`.

Comment: @Pascal I get: `Warning message:
'.find.package' is deprecated.
Use 'find.package' instead.
See help("Deprecated") ` Thanks for taking the time, by the way!

Comment: I don't. Did you use the same command?

Comment: @Pascal Apologies. I added in quotes. I get: `[1] nnet.default nnet.formula`

Comment: So you've got it. You can `edit(nnet.formula)`.

Comment: @Pascal Bam! Thanks! `trace("nnet.default", edit=TRUE)` works as well!  Post as a solution and I will mark it as solved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
methods(nnet)
[1] nnet.default nnet.formula

edit(nnet.formula)
```

As well as

```
trace("nnet.default", edit=TRUE)
```