# r modify and rebuild package

Tags: r, package, rebuild

I'm trying to use the SemiMarkov package and I want to change one small line of code in there. I've done some digging via:

```
getAnywhere("semiMarkov")
```

& I've identified that I want to change this line:

```
hessian <- diag(ginv(hessian(V, solution)))
```

to try something like:

```
hessian <- diag(ginv(pracma::hessian(V, solution)))
```

How do I go about this? Do I need to rebuild the package from scratch, and if so do I need rTools etc for this, or is there a simple-ish workaround (I'm a relevant R novice)? I've done some searching online and can't find anything obvious. Any ideas/pointers gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Linux environment

Starting with downloading the package source from CRAN.

- This is the landing page: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SemiMarkov/index.html
- This is the package source: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/SemiMarkov_1.4.2.tar.gz

Download and extract the source:

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/SemiMarkov_1.4.2.tar.gz
tar -xvzf SemiMarkov_1.4.2.tar.gz
```

This should result in a directory named `SemiMarkov`.  Open up the source (`cd SemiMarkov`), and modify as necessary.

Next, build the changes:

```
cd ..
R CMD build SemiMarkov/
```

This will result in a new archive file named `SemiMarkov_1.4.2.tar.gz`.

Lastly, install your modified archive:

```
R CMD INSTALL SemiMarkov_1.4.2.tar.gz
```

## Windows environment

I'm less familiar with the Windows platform.  *nix tooling is available in Cygwin, but it's painful.  Instead, as Josh O'Brien points out, you should follow the [Windows-specific instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) in the R Installation and Administration manual.

Comment: @Rob The general advice here (that you should compile a modified version of the package) is great. As a long-time Windows user myself, though, who has written and modified many packages, I would **very strongly** advise you against trying to do this with Cygwin.

Comment: Instead, you'll should *carefully* follow the [Windows-specific instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) in the R Installation and Administration manual. (The linked appendix notes, "*This appendix contains a lot of prescriptive comments. They are here as a result of bitter experience."* I'd suggest you take that warning seriously, if you want a relatively pain-free experience!) Once you've got the appropriate toolset  in place, installing the modified package will be as simple as doing `devtools::install("SemiMarkov")`.

Comment: Great pionts @JoshO'Brien :) Hope you don't mind, I updated my answer with your content.  Feel free to edit it!

Answer (score 41):

If you'd like to simply test out the effect of that change in an interactive R session, you can do so using `trace()`. Here's how:

1. Type `trace("semiMarkov", edit=TRUE)`
2. In the text editor that that launches, edit the line of interest.
3. Save the modified file.
4. Close the text editor
5. Back in R, use the modified function.

Comment: Many thanks, this also really helpful for a quick way of testing and very easy!

Comment: I didnt know about trace, but it is extremely helpful, thanks!