# R Shiny can not use shinytest for larger application

Tags: r, shiny, automated-tests

I need to test my shiny application so I have downloaded `shinytest` and followed this tutorial - https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/testing-shiny-applications-with-shinytest/ .

When I run `recordTest()` on a small application, it works fine. But I have a big application that I need to create tests for and I can not run `recordTest()` above this application. It outputs the following lines:

```
Error in sd_startShiny(self, private, path, seed) : 
  Cannot find shiny port number. Error:
Running application in test mode.
Loading required package: shiny

Attaching package: 'dplyr'

The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Loading required package: Hmisc
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: Formula

Attaching package: 'Hmisc'

The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':

    src, summarize

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    format.pval, units

Loading required package: SparseM

Attaching package: 'SparseM'

The following object is masked from 'package:base':

    backsolve


Attaching package: 'rms'

The following object is masked from 'package:shiny':

    validate

Loading required package: ggpubr
Loading required package: magrittr
Warning: package 'compareGroups' was built under R version 3.4.4
Loading required package: gdata
gdata: Unab
```

My application needs to be tested is quite big. It connects to database, retrieves data from database, sources many files. In lines printed above you can clearly see from the last line that it probably timeouts. `gdata: Unab` - probably it was meant `Unable ...`.

I saw people dealing with this here - https://github.com/rstudio/shinytest/issues/111 - but there is no clear answer how to fix that.

The solution may be: to rewrite `shinytest`'s code that is placed on github and install the rewritten one. But I do not know if this is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the right attitude how to fix problems like this but let's say. I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34800688/6124434) and changed the `loadTimeout = 10000` parameter to `loadTimeout = 100000`.

It was the following line of code:

```
app <- ShinyDriver$new(app, seed = seed, loadTimeout = 10000)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get past this problem simply by including a loadTimeout parameter when I called recordTest:

```
> recordTest("myApp", loadTimeout = 100000)
```

However, as scarface mentioned, you can also change the first line of the test script that is created by recordTest() by adding the loadTimeout parameter to the first line.