# How to edit R library source files in-place

Tags: r, debugging

This a follow-up to [How to edit and debug R library sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384598/how-to-edit-and-debug-r-library-sources). I'm wondering if there's an easy way to edit an R library source file and cause the edited file to be loaded by `library` without reinstalling the code. I'm asking this in the context of a library that I'm developing and am looking for an easy way to incrementally edit and test my code. I know about `source` and other ways of loading code into an R session, but I want to test scripts that do the usual `library` thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're developing a packages.  If that's the case then using the devtools package is probably what you want to do.  The `load_all()` function will systematically reload all of your code so you can make changes and test everything out.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I am using devtools and know about `load_all`

Comment: Sorry for the truncated comment above. Thanks for the prompt response. I am using devtools and know about `load_all()`. But I'm testing my package with scripts that use `library` and would like to avoid the need to modify the scripts when the package is installed.

Comment: I guess it's still not clear to me exactly what you're doing.