# Modify R function system-wide with insertSource

Tags: r

I would like to modify the "ace" function of the "ape" package according to the author's suggestion. I wrote the modified function to "ace2.r" and want to replace the standard "ace" function from the package by my function (seen here: [How to edit and debug R library sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384598/how-to-edit-and-debug-r-library-sources)):

`insertSource("ace2.r", package= "ape", functions="ace")`

but I get

`Warning message:
In insertSource("ace2.r", package = "ape", functions = "ace"): cannot insert these (not found in source): "ace"`

I checked ?insertSource but I don't get what should be given for "functions"

Comment: Hello Jibbah. Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question.  As currently stated, it's too vague to be effectively answered.

Comment: As background, why do you want to do this? I'm guessing it could harm the reproducibility of your work. If you want to use a custom function, why not just load it with `source("path/to/your/function.R")` at the start of a new script? Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile

Comment: so I reformulated my question. I followed Adam Smith's and Selcuk Akbas' suggestions and stored the modified function into a new script. However I would still like to know how to implement these changes into the package's function

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a function is a bit complex and risky, you can create your modified version with a new name. Let's say that function is ***substr***

Write ***substr*** in console and press enter, which will return

```
> substr
function (x, start, stop) 
{
if (!is.character(x)) 
x <- as.character(x)
.Internal(substr(x, as.integer(start), as.integer(stop)))
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000d7d4ec0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

then assign your own version with a new name (***my_substr***)

```
my_substr <- function (x, start, stop) 
{
if (!is.character(x)) 
x <- as.character(x)
.Internal(substr(x, as.integer(start), as.integer(stop)+1))
}
```